# Error with django middleware settings

Tags: python, django, apache

I am using django 1.7 and my middleware settings look like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

I am using apache2 as my web server. As the settings are, I get a 500 internal server error when I try to access my site. However, when I comment out `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware'`, everything works fine. Is there a related setting I'm missing? The apache error log is as follows:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class
```

Comment: What does the Apache error log say?

Comment: The apache error log says  -ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class

Comment: Are you sure you have 1.7? That class was introduced for 1.7 only, just before release. What is the result of `import django; print django.get_version()`?

Comment: Ah it's actually that on my production server - (1, 6, 1, 'final', 0). I got confused since on my local machine I developed the app with django 1.8

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem myself. The problem was caused by an installation that conflicted with certain "ssl" libraries installed by django.
Uninstall and re-install, solves this problem most efficiently.

I recommend, uninstall all the django versions:

"sudo pip uninstall django" several times until all the django distributions are uninstalled.

Then, re-install

"sudo pip install django"